# How to screenshot Netflix?

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, netflix

I am watching Netflix in Safari on macOS 10.13.3.

I just tried taking a screenshot through several methods:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> while Safari in full-screen mode (Netflix isn't).
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> and dragging while Safari in full-screen mode.
3. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> while Safari is not full-screen and not focussed.
4. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> and dragging while Safari is not full-screen and not focussed.

But none of these captured the screen, I get only black images.

How can I extract a frame from a show on Netflix?

Comment: Use another browser (chrome, firefox), Netflix has this on the W10 app as well.

Comment: May I recommend a camera?

Comment: @Mark I don't actually own a  camera outside of my webcam.

Comment: What happens when you use a third-party screen capture tool like Monosnap?

Comment: Just use the screenshot app, but use the 'select portion of the screen' mode, not 'grab entire screen'.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The source is the combination of Netflix and Safari, which disables screenshots and screencasts of its content to prevent piracy.

You should be able to take screenshots if you use Google Chrome:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to do it in Safari if possible

Comment: I don't understand apple's motivation. If anything this encourages and supports piracy b/c people will just go onto the illegal websites to be able to take the screens they want.

Comment: I'm sure that Netflix and Apple are in cahoots, legally, to prevent piracy, but you you can't do it in Safari. _No way around it._ One can't even hook a Mac up to a projector and use Netflix through Safari - the image is black. [This page](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/take-a-screenshot-in-netflix/) has some tips about running a Windows VM, which seems a little extreme when you can just use another browser.

Comment: @IconDaemon is totally correct. You'd need to run macOS in a VM and screen shot Safari from another OS to get around the programming that intentionally disables this when safari and the screen shot run together.

Comment: @theonlygusti The motivation isn't to prevent screenshots - it's to prevent recording of an entire movie. Prevention of stills is just a side-effect.

Comment: The effect of two evils combined: Closed source and DRM.

Comment: Chrome works perfectly for Netflix screenshots.

Comment: @IconDaemon so you mention that you can't even hook up a projector. I haven't tested that. Weirdly (perhaps?) Mirror for Samsung TV perfectly plays Netflix on the TV. I wonder how it manages to do that.

Comment: no longer the case as of May 2022.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work on Firefox anymore either. But Firefox itself does have a screenshot function, and that seems to work!

Answer (score 4):

I'm submitting this as an answer because I feel this is better answers "How to do this in Safari", even though there is already an accepted solution.

I really hate to suggest third party software, but in this instance, try Greenshot.  It's lightweight, and simple to use.

NOTE: SADLY, I just checked, and it is 1.99USD on OSX. Here is a list of alternatives:

https://screenshot.net/greenshot-for-mac.html

https://www.apowersoft.com/mac-screenshot is the top hit (in case link becomes defunct)

Comment: Have you tried using Greenshot to see if it works?

Comment: Yes.  Greenshot works fine.  It stands alone and is therefore not restricted by the boundaries of external software.  I just dislike not using built-in solutions, hence my apprehension for recommending it.  downvote accepted on the assumption people don't comprehend the answer.

Comment: Hidden spam. Greenshot does not work on Mac at all. The links go to a site promoting the original posters products (or more likely the ones he's paid to promote).

Comment: If anyone has a relationship with software, it’s best to disclose that. That being said, a single post that tries to answer the question isn’t necessarily spam. Please flag as other if anyone detects a campaign to astroturf this produce and we will look into spam violations.

Comment: Mac Screenshot does not work as of May 2022: the pane showing Netflix (Chrome) is black.

Comment: @MattiasMartens use Firefox and its screenshot function :)

Answer (score 1):

Yah. I always used firefox before a few days ago, and never had that problem. What you can do though, is taking a portion of the image you want to screenshot; that way it works out without a hitch (just gotta get the dimensions right). Basically, don't take a 'full screen' screen shot, and use alt+4 but make it a bit smaller to bypass their privacy policy.

My best bet is that Safari and Netflix have implemented this policy not for screenshots per se, but to prevent recording the video playing and torrenting it. But, because they couldn't address the problem directly, they had to cooperate and do it at the source, i.e. to prevent any and all images (moving or not) from getting recorded. How futile :P