# Extension/userscript for Safari that allows Netflix screenshotting

Tags: macos, safari, screen-capture, netflix

Is it possible to make a Safari extension, or userscript, that would allow Netflix videos to be screenshotted?

Does anyone know how Apple are disabling Netflix screenshotting in Safari and whether this can be bypassed with an extension or userscript?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but have you tried using Chrome?

Comment: You can use that as a workaround.

Comment: @Josh [I know](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316097/150109)

Comment: The on topic version of this has already been [asked and answered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316097/5472).