# udemy videos show up as a black window/region in screenshots

Tags: macos, screen-capture

To avoid the udemy-black-screen, the recommendations I have seen are to disable Hardware Acceleration. But it is hard-coded to Enabled from `Catalina` onwards

[image]

Is there any way to capture the (paused) video of Udemy?   I am on `Sonoma 14.2.1`, using the built-in display and this happens on both `Edge`, `Chrome`, and `Safari`.

Comment: Which browser are you using? What is your Mac and if you are using an external display, does this happen when the browser is displayed within either the internal or the external display? If it is only when the browser is displayed in the external display, what is the make and model of the external display and how is it connected to the Mac?

Comment: @Alper  I am on `Sonoma 14.2.1`, using the built-in display and this happens on both `Edge`, `Chrome`, and `Safari`.

Comment: This is by design and I don’t think many browsers will allow this now. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/316096/5472

Comment: @bmike  fyi `Youtube` screenshots work - it's just `Udemy` that does not.  I wonder how they managed that - is that app using  an API to interact with the browser to disable the capability

Comment: I believe YouTube isn’t coding their streams as protected. Let me see if I can get the details from Apple Developer for you to inspect the players for both. Also, I’ll add a video capture hardware recommendation. You can likely get a video recorder that won’t enforce HDCP on HDMI.